# What is the big difference between SAS and ACS in Azure Authorization?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-blob-storage, azure-acs

I´ve done some "Googling" to figure out the big difference between SAS and ACS Azure Authorization strategy and I could not find something that really have convinced me.
Could someone point me the best cenario when to use one or another and the differences between then?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

SAS tokens are one of the authz capabilities that the Storage service exposes for delegating access to storage resources. You can delegate a subset of privileges to specific resources for a specific period of time. You can read more about it [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/). ACS is an access control capability that is available for many Azure workloads - but has not yet been integrated to support Storage. You can read more about ACS [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2012/12/21/acs-in-windows-azure-management-portal/).

Storage enables three main ways to restrict access to resources:

1. Storage account access keys
2. SAS Tokens
3. Blobs can also be configured to private access, public container or public blob.

There is also a good whitepaper on Security, Privacy and Compliance that you can find [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/security/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I know how to use SAS and ACS. For example, nowadays, when a service bus is created an ACS is not associated to it anymore. Why should I prefer to use SAS instead of ACS? Disregarding the fact that I can create temporary accesses with SAS, I cannot see great advantages in using the SAS instead of ACS. So I'm still waiting for a reply that convinces me.